# Using non ionic-native cordova plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

i am trying to integrate [This]https://github.com/louisbl/cordova-plugin-locationservices  plugin into my ionic 4 app.

since its a non ionic-native plugin, how do i go about calling its functions withing my typescript code?

i have tried using  `declare var locationservices: any;
locationServices.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,[geolocationError],geolocationOptions]);`

but i get an error that locationservices is not defined

Answer (score 1):

so instead of using `declare var locationservices: any` i used `declare var cordova: any;`

```
`declare var cordova: any;
cordova.plugins.locationServices.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
         console.log(position)
      }
    );`
```

NB:the code will always result to undefined when tested on a browser, it needs to be tested on a device